# From user-agent string determine what browser made the request

Tags: linux, awk, logfile

I am trying to write a batch file for reading and extracting user agent from a log file which i am able to do with the following code but i need to give numeric count of the browser that made the requests and Using gnu-plot, plot a bar-chart of the number of requests per browser.i am kinda stuck with the browser requests a little help or direction will be appreciated.

Cheers.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 # All we're doing here is extracting the user agent field from the log file and 'piping' it through some other commands. The first sort is to # enable uniq to properly identify and count unique user agents. The final sort orders the result by number and name (both descending).

 awk -F\" '{print $6}' access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -fr > extracteduseragents.txt
```

Comment: What are you stuck on exactly? Taking that output and getting it into gnuplot?

Comment: @EtanReisner Thank you for your response , i am stuck with, after Extracting  the user-agent string which is done by the above mentioned code i want to determine what browser made the request?

Comment: The User-Agent string *is* the browser identifier. You can map those strings to friendlier names manually if you want but that's about it. There's a reason doing UA-sniffing on web pages is a strongly discouraged practice.

Answer (score 1):

To get friendlier names for the browsers, you can use e.g. [pybrowscap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pybrowscap/) together with the `browscap.csv` file from http://tempdownloads.browserscap.com/index.php.

Then you could use a script like the following `sanitize_ua.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from pybrowscap.loader.csv import load_file

browscap = load_file('browscap.csv')

for ua in sys.stdin:
    browser = browscap.search(ua)
    if browser:
        print "'{} {}'".format(browser.name(), browser.version())
```

And run from the command line like

```
awk -F\" '{print $6}' access.log | sort | python sanitize_ua.py | uniq -c | sort -fr
```

Of course, searching all user agents before `uniq` is very unefficient, but it should show the working principle. And, of course, you could also write a single python script to do all the processing.